# forking and pid

Tags: c, linux, fork

The code:

```
int main(void) 
{
    printf("pid: %d\n", getpid());
    pid = fork();


    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed!");
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        execv("sum", argv);
    } else {
        printf("  pid: %d\n", pid);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
pid: 280
   pid: 281
```

The question:

Why are the two pid's different. I thought they should be the same because the parent is what is executing in the `else` block and the parent is what is executing before the fork so they should be the same, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
RETURN VALUE
       On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, 
       and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent,
       no child process  is  created,  and  errno  is  set appropriately.
```

So, in the parent process, fork() returns the pid of the child process that was created.

Comment: herp derp. I thought it returned the id of the parent. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I won't repeat [nos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233707/forking-and-pid/6233724#6233724), as he's entirely correct. But I'd point out that any program can retrieve it's own PID with the `getpid` system call. So there's no reason for the fork to return you *own* PID. Instead, you may want to know the PID of the process you just forked off, which may be difficult to obtain if it wasn't returned (to the parent) by `fork`.

Comment: additionally, every process can get the pid of its parent via `getppid()`, but there's no syscall to get the pid of the child (there could be many children).